# capture and export multiple named groups to csv

Tags: regex, powershell

I’d like to capture two particular data from the input files using regular expressions like this:

```
$reg = [regex]"(?<Name>^Name:.*)|(?<Id>^Id:.*)"
gci C:\test\*.txt | Get-Content | Select $reg -allmatches | Select -Expand Matches|
...
new-object psobject -property @{Name=$n; Id=$i}
...
Select-Object Name, Id | Export-Csv c:\info.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

The problem I faced is some files don't have 'Id' entry. If any file doesn't have the 'Id' entry in it, it doesn't show up in the exported csv file. I'd greatly appreciate if someone could help me come up with the solution.

`C:\test\file1.txt` contains:

```
Name: Sturgeon Ocean   
Alias: Socean   
Id: 384932   
Address: 3600 Caviar  
Street, Pacific beach   
...   
Cell: 389-394-3843   
...
```

Comment: Each file only contains one user record?

Comment: Yes, each file only contains one user record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but I think this should work:

```
Foreach ($file in gci C:\test\*.txt)
 { 
   $Record = New-object PSObject -Property @{Name=$null;ID=$null}
   Foreach ($line in Get-Content $file.FullName)
    {
      switch -Regex ($_)
      {
       '^Name' {$Record.Name = ($_ -replace '^Name:(.+)$','$1').Trim()}
       '^ID'   {$Record.ID   = ($_ -replace '^ID:(.+)$','$1').Trim()}
      }
    }
    $Record
 }
```

No switch

```
$reg = [regex]"(^Name:.*)|(^Id:.*)"

gci c:\new*.txt | 
foreach {
          $matched = (gc reg_test0.txt) -match $reg -replace '^.+:\s*',''
           new-object psobject -Property @{Name=$matched[0];ID=$matched[1]} 
        }| Select Name,Id | Export-Csv c:\new\info.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I copied your script into PS ISE, and ran it. But it retuns like below
ID       Name
---      ------

Comment: using switch statement the following script works with one issue. $reg = [regex]"(?<Name>^Name:.*)|(?<ID>^ID:.*)"
gci c:\new\*.txt | Get-Content | select-string $reg -allmatches | Select -Expand Matches | % {switch -Wildcard ($_.value) {"Name:*" {$n=$_.ToString()} "ID:*" {$i=$_.ToString();new-object psobject -property @{Name=$n; ID=$i} } }} | Select Name, ID | Export-Csv c:\new\info.csv -NoTypeInformation. If the 'ID' entry is missing in a input file that person's name won't show up in csv. I still want to solve my problem using pattern not switch statement

Comment: OK.  I added a solution that doesn't use a switch.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked even the 'ID' entry is missing in an input file. You're really good at it. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't forget to mark the question as answered if you're happy with the solution.